# double definition of function because of rvalue reference

Tags: c++, function, rvalue

So my problem is this:

What I have in my .h

```
class PlayerClass
{
//Class declaration
//...
std::vector<sf::ConvexShape> parts;

void addShape(sf::ConvexShape& sShape);
void addShape(sf::ConvexShape&& sShape);
};
```

What I have in my .cpp

```
void PlayerClass::addShape(sf::ConvexShape& sShape)
{
    //processing
    //...

    parts.push_back(sShape);
}
void PlayerClass::addShape(sf::ConvexShape&& sShape)
{
   //processing
   //...

   parts.push_back(sShape);
}
```

At this point, I have to copy paste what I have in my `PlayerClass::addShape` definition and overload for a rvalue reference
I wish I would just need to copy element in my vector, hence no need for reference, but `std::Vector::push_back` is defined to take parameters by reference, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

So that's what's bothering me, I always have to double copy my functions to comply to reference taken parameters behaviour (`std::Vector::push_back` in this case)

I can't use a  `const aClass&` because if I use a temporary object to call my function, my vector's iterator would point toward something that's been deleted

Comment: If you write the same code for an rvalue reference as for an lvalue reference, then you're doing something wrong. You really should only have one overload, taking `const&`.

Comment: And you really shouldn't have "hundreds of lines" in a single function.  :-)

Comment: I have a vector in my class, and I want to add object to that vector, that's what I'm doing in my function, if I pass a temporary object then it would be deallocated at the end of my function call, and my vector would have an iterator pointing something that's been deleted no? that's why I need a rvalue reference overload to extend its lifetime to my class'

Comment: You can always use forwarding references, however, that also brings its own kind of ugliness as it forces templates and by result the code in the header. Often, I only add the C&& overload when profiling tells me I need it.

Comment: What's in your vector is not the function argument - it's a separate object copied or moved from the function argument. Their lifetimes are independent (that's assuming you actually have a vector of objects, and not, say, a vector of pointers to objects; if it's the latter, then I'm not sure how your rvalue overload is supposed to work at all). In any case, rather than describing what your code is doing in prose, show a [mcve].

Comment: Your last statement is really questionable, `push_back` copies or moves the object into the `std::vector`, so unless your temporary object is some strange form of pointer which destroys the pointed to object when just one reference to it gets removed using `const &` should work just fine

Comment: but why is `std::Vector::push_back` overloaded for a rvalue reference then? If `const&` works just fine as you've said

Comment: `parts.push_back(sShape);` should be `parts.push_back(std::move(sShape));` in the second one

Comment: I would just have one function that takes argument by value, and provide a forwarding emplace

Comment: your comment about `const&`  "vector iterator point to something deleted" makes no sense. Vectors store copies of the pushed item

Comment: ups, you're right, I didn't read the second line "The content of val is copied (or moved) to the new element."

Answer (score 1):

If `sf::ConvexShape` is cheaply movable, just provide a single overload taking by copy:

```
void PlayerClass::addShape(sf::ConvexShape sShape)
{
    //processing
    //...

    parts.push_back(std::move(sShape));
}
```

This covers all cases well with negligible overhead:

- from inside your function to the vector, you only pay a move;
- if the caller is passing you an object that it is still interested about, he'll pass it as is, so it will be copied - but just once, which is a copy you would have done anyhow to put it into the vector;
- if the caller is passing you an object that he don't need around anyhow, he'll do `addShape(std::move(sShape))`, which will just pay two moves.

If instead you have an lvalue and an rvalue reference overloads as you did, you can be extra cheap even around moves (you avoid one move in the cases above), but in 99% cases it's just a useless complication that leads to code duplication, as moves are expected to be virtually free anyhow.

In most code that deals with movable types taking by copy if you eventually want to own a copy the parameter is the right thing - ideally, you don't want to see an rvalue reference parameter outside of the move constructor.